# Is there really any way to reserve saved games for Games for Windows Live platform?

Tags: games-for-windows-live

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate. Recently, I backed up my Games for Windows Live profile folder (I only use offline profile) and Street Fighter IV (a game for GFWL platform) save game folder. Then reinstalled Windows and restored the backed up folders. After launching SF4 on new OS, I've noticed that my GFWL profile is restored but SF4 couldn't recognize my saved games and it creates new saved game folder for me!

What can I do to preserve save games of GFWL platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Fallout 3.  What I ended up doing was installing GFWL on the fresh version of Windows, looked for the newly created save game folder, and copied my backups directly in there (the **folder** that was created...I didn't overwrite them).

My memory is a bit hazy at this point because I started freaking out that I'd lost my save games, but I'm pretty sure that something was named slightly differently with my new profile.

Maybe what you should do, is start up a round of SF4 and save your game.  Then look to see where the new save game is located and overwrite it with your pre-existing versions?

Comment: ok i'll try that and get back to you. i was wondering how did you install GFWL, i don't have to do that!

Comment: i've noticed that being frustrated, i deleted the sf4 saved games! stupid me! will try it later with another game.

Comment: @Donotalo: I believe that GFWL was installed when I installed Fallout 3...I could be wrong as it has been some time....